# Scrapy ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping, scrapy, pipeline

The problem i am facing is that Scrapy code, specifically pipeline presents me with a Programming error
`mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement'`

This is my code for the pipeline:

```
import csv
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy import log
import sys
import mysql.connector

class CsvWriterPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='test', password='test', db='test')
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT title, url FROM items WHERE title= %s", item['title'])
        result = self.cursor.fetchone()
        if result:

            log.msg("Item already in database: %s" % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        else:
            self.cursor.execute(
               "INSERT INTO items (title, url) VALUES (%s, %s)",
                    (item['title'][0], item['link'][0]))
            self.connection.commit()

            log.msg("Item stored : " % item, level=log.DEBUG)
        return item

    def handle_error(self, e):
            log.err(e)
```

It gives me this exact error when i run the spider.
 http://hastebin.com/xakotugaha.py

As u can see, it clearly crawls so i doubt anything wrong with the spider.

I am currently using Scrapy web crawler with MySql database. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening while you are making a SELECT query. There is a single placeholder in the query, but `item['title']` is a list of strings - it has multiple values:

```
self.cursor.execute("SELECT title, url FROM items WHERE title= %s", item['title'])
```

The root problem is actually *coming from the spider*. Instead of having a single item being returned with multiple links and titles - you need to return a separate item for every link and title.

---

Here is the code of the spider that should work for you:

```
import scrapy

from scrapycrawler.items import DmozItem


class DmozSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["snipplr.com"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for i in range(1, 146):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url("https://snipt.net/public/?page=%d" % i)

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//article/div[2]/div/header/h1/a'):
            item = DmozItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('text()').extract()
            item['link'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract()
            yield item
```

Comment: I see, how would want go about doing this ? it worked before but for some reason stopped working.
This is the spider code if u need it:
http://hastebin.com/yalivovifo.py

Comment: ah, does
`for sel in response.xpath('//article/div[2]/div/header/h1/a'):` have any diffrence compared to this ? `sel = Selector(response)`

Comment: @CharlieC it's just that you need to yield item instances from inside the loop, for every link. Hope that makes things work.